# FirePhone - launch icons not populating?

Tags: android, homescreen, kindle-fire

For some reason in the latest version of my App, the app loads and runs from IDEA, but the launch icon doesn't show up on the home screen or in the grid.  Oddly, it was working fine in an earlier build, which is currently being sold on the Amazon Ap store and works as expected when downloaded, but the updated version isn't working.   I've made a number of changes to my development environment and have tried resizing widgets and providing a widget in the default drawable folder, but its not making any difference.

Does anyone have a suggestion what to look at that might explain the behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I haven't been able to find out exactly why this happened, but I was able to find a workaround.
The app I was working was a new revision of an App already published ot the Amazon App store.  I purchased a copy of the app from the store just to check, so the original (V.1.0) app itself was showing up on my list of apps in the cloud.  The new version I am working on (V.1.1) is the version on which the icons weren't showing up when I ran it from Android Studio.

The workaround that worked was to a) to delete the app from my cloud, and b) to change the Application attribute android:label to a different name.  After I did that, the icon showed up again on my FirePhone.  not sure which of these two changes did the trick, maybe both are not necessary, but in case anybody else is running into this problem...

Answer (score 0):

There is a simple solution for this.
If you want your app to be compatible for both Android and Kindle you have to make the necessary icon adjustments for Kindle. Add the custom drawable folders to your project.

```
custom drawable "drawable-1024x600-v10" with ic_launcher.png for KindleFire 1 st Gen
custom drawable "drawable-1024x600-v15" with ic_launcher.png for KindleFire 2nd Gen
custom drawable "drawable-1280x800" with ic_launcher.png for  KindleFire HD-7'
custom drawable "drawable-1920x1200" with ic_launcher.png for  KindleFire HD-8.9'
```

Do not replace the drawable folders you currently have for Android, just add to them. Alternatively, you can replace your mdpi icon with 200x200 (will display blurry on some kindles such as the fireHDx) or 512x512 (for better results).